# Missile don't fire

Tags: java, applet

I am stuck with the missile part. How do I add a method `fire()` (from `Missile.java`) in the `Player` class when `keyPressed` occurred. Once I press space the missile shoots and adds to ArrayList of missile objects. But it's not happening.

```
private  ArrayList<Missilies> missilies;

public Player (MainClass mc){
    url = mc.getDocumentBase();
    player = mc.getImage(url,"spaceship1.png");

}

public void paint(Graphics g, MainClass mc){
    g.drawImage(player, x, y, mc);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:{
        // fire a missile;

        missilies.add(new Missilies(x, y));
        ArrayList ms = (Missilies).
        missilies.add(new Missilies(getX(), getY()));
        break;
        }
```

and here's the Missile class

```
public class Missilies {

 //  New missile object  ////////

 public Missilies(int x, int y){

    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

     visible=true;

 }

 //  Moving missiles ////////

 public void update(MainClass mc, Player p){
     x +=missile_speed;
     if (x>mc.getWidth())
         visible = false;
 }

 //  Painting  ////////

 public void paint(Graphics g, MainClass mc, Player p) {

        for (int i = 0; i < missilies.size(); i++ ) {

            Missilies m = (Missilies) missilies.get(i);
            g.drawImage(missile, p.getX(), p.getY(), mc);
        }


    }

 // Firing new missile  ///////////

 public  void fire(Player p){
     missilies.add(new Missilies(p.getX(), p.getY()));
 }

 // Action performed //////////

 public void action(MainClass mc, Player p){

     for (int i = 0; i < missilies.size(); i++) {
         Missilies m = (Missilies) missilies.get(i);
         if (visible == true) 
             update(mc, p);
         else missilies.remove(i);
     }
 }
```

}

Main class

```
public void init()
{
    setSize(800, 600);
    p = new Player(this);
    e = new Enemy(this);
} 

{
    while(running)
    {
        repaint();
        p.update(this);
        e.update(this, p);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }

        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error has occured");
        }

    }



}

public void update(Graphics g){
    dbImage = createImage(800,600);
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paint(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    //g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.paint(g, this);
    e.paint(g, this);
}

}
```

Comment: **WHAT** is not happening? the missile stuff doesn't happen? It fires but doesn't get added to your list? it goes off target and nukes your dog?

Comment: _There must be some technical problem in your missile??_ :)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Nobody is going to wade through a wall of code to debug this.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't get added to list. It gives me NullPointerException at missilies.add(new Missilies(x, y));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Some suggestions for your question - please be sure to clean up the code that you post and only post relevant sections, it's very hard to read cluttered code like this. And as Marc B said, it's tough to tell what you're actually asking, so please be clear in your question and tell us what you've already tried.

From what I can tell, you're having trouble calling the Missilies.fire (sic) method from the keyPressed event handler. Let's break this down, since you need to do 3 things:

1. Create the missile. Nothing else will work until you create an instance of the Missilies class. Calling Missilies.fire won't work because that's like telling the engineers to fire the missile blueprints rather than actually firing a missile. `Missilies newMissile = new Missilies(x,y);`
2. Fire the missile. NOW you can call `fire` on the instance you've created: `newMissile.fire(this);`
3. Finally, you can add the missile that you've created to your array: `missilies.add(newMissile);`

Again, it's really hard to read your code so take my suggestions with a grain of salt. Please do try to clean up the question!

**edit:** Based on your comment clarification above about the NullPointerException, it's much clearer what the problem is: you're not initializing your missilies ArrayList! You should make sure that you initialize every object you have before using it. You need a line like `missilies = new ArrayList<Missilies>();` in your `public Player (MainClass mc)` function. I'm not going to go through all your code, but you should go through and check that you've initialized every other object as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'll work on my code and definitely clean it up.

Comment: Based on your NullPointerException comment, I've added an edit to my answer. See above.

Comment: Thanks! It's all good now.